# Searching for files with custom properties

Tags: google-apps-script

I've created a custom file property where key = "favorite" and value is the current user name. This property is public as I'd like to be able to see what files are tagged as favorites in a shared folder for each user from another account.

The issue is I think I am limited to only searching on a specific key/value pair like this:

```
function listFiles() {
  var currentUser = Drive.About.get().name;
  var optionalArgs = {
    maxResults: 100,
    **q: "properties has { key='favorite' and value='"+currentUser+"' and visibility='PUBLIC' }",**
    spaces: "drive"
  };
  var response = Drive.Files.list(optionalArgs);
  var files = response.items;
}
```

But I'd like to search on key='favorite' without specifying a value. Is that possible? What's the syntax?

Comment: Have you resolved this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this [snippet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app) that finds all the files in Google Drive using Appscript:

```
var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
   while (files.hasNext()) {
   var file = files.next();
}
```

You need to specify the value in a key-value pair because it is the data that is being identified.

NOTE: Make sure that you set [custom properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive#adding_custom_properties) when working with custom files:

```
function addCustomProperty(fileId) {
   var property = {
   key: 'department',
   value: 'Sales',
   visibility: 'PUBLIC'
};
Drive.Properties.insert(property, fileId);
}
```